# full join & where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select *
from Table1
full join Table2 on Table2.Common = Table1.Common
```

In the above query, I want to add this `where` condition:

```
where (Table1.StatusId > 100 or Table1.StatusId is not null)
```

`StatusId` is of datatype `numeric(18, 2)`.

The problem is when I use the `where` condition, rows in `Table2` which don't have any connecting data in `Table1` are not showing up anymore.

Is there any other way to add this `where` condition?

Comment: You are checking Table1's fields in the WHERE clause and you are expecting that those null values from Table1 will be shown? Maybe you need the second part of condition like: "or Table1.StatusId is null"

Comment: `where (Table1.StatusId > 100 or Table1.StatusId is not null)` does not make any sense.  It is equivalent to `where Table1.StatusId is not null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try put it on a [Subquery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    *
          FROM      Table1
          WHERE     ( Table1.StatusId > 100
                      OR Table1.StatusId IS NOT NULL
                    )
        ) T
        FULL JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Common = t.Common
```

Comment: Thank you. this one worked. Thank you everyone for giving me solutions & helping me:)

Answer (score 1):

Move the `t1.StatusId is NOT NULL` filter to `ON` condition

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 t1
       FULL JOIN Table2 t2
              ON t1.Common = t1.Common
                 AND t1.StatusId is NOT NULL
```

The problem in your query is, in `table1` status column for the non matching records `NULL` values will be present which will be filtered by applying the Where condition `Where t1.StatusId is NOT NULL`. So move it to `ON` clause which tells what are the records to joined instead of filtering the result

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `AND (Table1.StatusId > 100 or Table1.StatusId is not null)` after your ON-Statement

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Table2
Full join Table1 on Table2.Common = Table1.Common
where (Table2.StatusId > 100 or Table2.StatusId is not null)
```

Comment: In case with existing "Table1.StatusId is not null" condition in WHERE clause (as described in the question) it is not important what join you are using, because it will be equivalent to INNER JOIN.

Comment: there are 3 case. data in table1 only; data in table 1&2, data in table 2 only; thats why i used full join. i've to add where condition for table1. so for the above case 3, if there is no data in table1, data is not fetched from table2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the where condition to the result of the join condition then

> select *
>   from Table1
>   full join Table2 on Table2.Common = Table1.Common where Table1.StatusId > 100 or Table1.StatusId is not null

This result will probably not have the data from Table2 which has no connected data from Table1 because of your condition(Table1.StatusId is not null).

If you want the join to condition to be executed for only filtered records of Table1 then

> select * from Table2 full join (select * from Table1 where StatusId > 100 or StatusId is not null ) T on Table2.Common = T.Common